# Warning: POST Content-Length of 31491450 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Tags: laravel

I am uploading large size video in database but found above error I am changing setting of php.ini file as

upload_max_filesize=2000M
post_max_size=8000M

Small size file is easily uploaded but large size file give error as above

Comment: Did you restart your webserver?

Comment: @MaartenDev yes sir i restarted xampp

Comment: What ini file did you change? It that one currently loaded if you check `<?php phpinfo();`